# How can I install the Atom RPM package on Android?

Tags: rpm, android

I am relatively new to the Linux world, and I have the understanding that RPM is a package standard among Linux dependencies.

I have been wanting to install Atom editor on my favorite tablet, which has the lastest version of Android.

Here is a link on the packages: https://atom.io/docs/v0.194.0/getting-started-installing-atom

I could download them, but what are the next steps to installing it on Android?

Comment: Android is not a Linux system. It's a different operating system that happens to use the same kernel.

Comment: With [Android NDK][NDK] you can turn the source code into an actual APK that can install programs written in certain code like C for example [NDK]: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android doesn't use RPM as its package format, it uses [APKs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package). While there's nothing in theory that prevents building an RPM package manager for Android, that wouldn't be sufficient for what you're trying to do - the RPM would have to be built specifically for Android and for the platform your Android runs on (some form or ARM CPU or Intel Atom chip, usually), and the application needs to support the Android environment.

Atom isn't available for Android as of now. The pre-built packages are available for MacOS X, Windows and Linux, but only on x86_64 (i.e. usual desktop environments). Given that the application is quite complex (requires notably Node.js and a Chromium fork, and all their dependencies), porting it would be non-trivial work - that and [getting the performance right](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3322#issuecomment-52597731).